# elseif in while subpage

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create elseif´s for each row...I can´t figure out how to do it...tried to google (elseif in while)...hope someone could give me a hint to solve this...

```
$subgalSql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM galerieCategories ORDER BY title ASC");
        while($subgalData = mysql_fetch_array($subgalSql)){


        elseif($_GET[galeriepath] == $subgalData[title]){
         ?>HTML HERE<?
        }


        }
```

I hope someone can see what i´m trying to do here...the elseif are going to be subpages...

Thanks for any advice :)

Comment: where is the `IF` that the `elseif` is a sub condition of? Try just plain old `IF` instead

Comment: The first if is if(empty) for the mainpage. i don´t want to get another if into the while...this should be only for the subpages

Comment: Then your nesting method is wrong. you need to set a variable in the original IF and test for it inside the while loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"elseif" is only used as a secondary "if" statement.

```
if (condition) {
 //if condition is true
} elseif (condition2){
 //otherwise, if condition 2 is true
} else {
 //all else
}
```

Long story short: what you want is just an "if", since it's the first (and only) condition.

This should work:

```
    $subgalSql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM galerieCategories ORDER BY title ASC");
    while($subgalData = mysql_fetch_array($subgalSql)){
       if($_GET[galeriepath] == $subgalData[title]){
           ?>HTML HERE<?
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$subgalSql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM galerieCategories ORDER BY title ASC");
while($subgalData = mysql_fetch_array($subgalSql)){

   if($_GET[galeriepath] == $subgalData[title]){
      //HTML HERE
   }
   elseif(/*some condition here*/){
       // Code if it satifies the conditon
   } 
}
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

Answer (score 0):

you cannot place an elseif inside the primary condition, it has to follow on after its end.

```
// what I think your trying to do
if()
{
     while()
     {
          elseif()
          {
          }
     }
}
```

what you should do

```
if($x='y')
{
    $elsecondtion=false;
}
else
{
    $elsecondtion=true;
}

$subgalSql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM galerieCategories ORDER BY title ASC");
while($subgalData = mysql_fetch_array($subgalSql)){
    if($elsecondition && $_GET[galeriepath] == $subgalData[title]){
     ?>HTML HERE<?
    }

}
```